# Is a subgraph of G always connected

Tags: graphs, graph-traversal

I am trying to figure out if given a connect graph with N nodes and A edges, its subgraphs are connected.

In order word: given a graph G, can I have a subgraph of G that is not connected?
Or: can a subpgraph of G not be connected?

I think the answer is no because otherwise G' is not a (sub)graph.

Comment: Graph theory has a different term for what you think is a subgraph: it's called a [component](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_(graph_theory)).

Answer (score 1):

A subgraph of a graph $G$ is any graph that has a subset of $G$'s vertices and a subset of its edges.  In particular, for an graph $G=(V,E)$, the graph $(V,\emptyset)$ is a subgraph that's not connected.

Comment: So are you saying that a graph with only one edge is a subgraph not connected of G?

Comment: No, he's saying that if you remove all the edges from a graph, it is a subgraph, and it's not connected.

Comment: I'm saying a graph with _no_ edges is a non-connected subgraph of $G$. A graph with exactly one edge is connected if it only has two vertices, and disconnected if it has more than two.

Comment: @DavidRicherby the graph $(V,\emptyset)$ is a subgraph that's not connected except when $V$ is a set of a single vertex.

Comment: @Apass.Jack I can never remember whether people consider the single-vertex graph to be connected so I mostly just ignore it! 

Comment: @DavidRicherby I would believe you intended to say you could never remember whether people consider the graph with no vertex to be connected so you mostly just ignore it. A single-vertex graph is, by all means, connected. All people agree to that all the time.

Comment: @Apass.Jack No, I meant what I wrote. $K_1$ is not $1$-connected, since the definition of $k$-connected is that the graph has at least $k+1$ vertices and [blahblah]. So if you want to believe that $1$-connected is the same thing as connected, $K_1$ is not connected.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Now I see you point. It makes sense to define or deduce **a**) $K_1$ is 0-vertex-connected and **b**) being 0-vertex-connected or 1-vertex-connected is the same thing as being connected. However, I could not find anybody has ever mentioned 0-vertex-connected. There are a ton of further hair-splitting that can be done. I will maintain that a single-vertex graph is connected since that applies to, often very naturally or very conveniently, all the situations I have been interested in such as tree of a single node, forest, union-find data structure and, most importantly, topology.